# C# / Xamarin how to make 24hour count down timer from one point

Tags: c#, android, timer, xamarin.android

here is what i want to do.
i'm using Xamarin Android and trying to make a 24hour count down timer.

1. the timer text should be updated every second
2. when the app relaunches it should continue with saved time.

`DateTime timeStartedCountDown;`

3. timer should calculate time from one point. (not runtime delay)

eg) **what i want =**

`DateTime timeStartedCountDown;`

every second

`DisplayLeftTime(24 + (timeStartedCountDown - currentTime))` ? some like this

**not what i want =**

```
int timeElapsed;
```

every second

```
timeElapsed += 1;
text.Text = twentyFourHoursSec - timeElapsed
```

i'm not familiar with time & Threading sorry..

ps. android java code is fine!

Comment: What have you tried and What is the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This starts a timer the first time you open the app.

It recalls the startTime by using ISharedPreferences. And updates the date each second in the Thread.

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
    Thread thread;
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);

        ISharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences (this);
        ISharedPreferencesEditor editor = prefs.Edit ();

        long memStartTime = prefs.GetLong ("startTime", 0);
        if (memStartTime != 0) {
            startTime = new DateTime (memStartTime);
        } else {
            editor.PutLong ("startTime", startTime.Ticks);
            editor.Apply();
        }
        TimerUpdate ();
    }

    void TimerUpdate () {
        if (thread == null) {
            thread = new Thread (delegate () {
                while (true) {
                    Thread.Sleep (1000);
                    DateTime curTime = DateTime.Now;
                    Console.WriteLine (curTime - startTime);
                    //Update your on screen textview.
                }
            });
            thread.Start ();
        }
    }
}
```